# Identifying birth family of Abram Frank, possibly from Bessarabia?

Tags: birth-records, naturalization, 1860s, 1850s, bessarabia

Abe Frank (1/15/1859 - 11/18/1925), buried in B'Nai Israel Cemetery, Jackson, Tennessee, was married to Betty (11/13/1859 - 7/1/1927), also known as Bodgie. Their daughter Dora, my grandmother, married Joseph Freedman.

Abe and Betty lived in Nashville and Jackson, TN; in Jackson, Abe was involved in retail sales with the Kisbers, who married into the Frank family.  I remember vaguely a conversation from my childhood indicating that Abe was from Bessarabia.  I have looked on several online databases and come up empty.

I'm looking for birthplace(s) of Abe and Betty, and names of their parents.

---

For Abe, these three Census Records suggest a birthplace of Germany or Romania, and an immigration date of 1889:

- "United States Census, 1900," database with images, FamilySearch (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:MS87-BZT : 22 January 2015), Abe Frank, Nashville city Ward 12, Davidson, Tennessee, United States; citing sheet 3B, family 67, NARA microfilm publication T623 (Washington, D.C.: National Archives and Records Administration, n.d.); FHL microfilm 1,241,564.
- "United States Census, 1910," database with images, FamilySearch (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:MGXX-M1W : 29 October 2015), Abe Frank, Jackson Ward 4, Madison, Tennessee, United States; citing enumeration district (ED) ED 177, sheet 10B, NARA microfilm publication T624 (Washington, D.C.: National Archives and Records Administration, n.d.); FHL microfilm 1,375,524.
- "United States Census, 1920," database with images, FamilySearch (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:MNR9-KG6 : 14 December 2015), Abraham Frank, Jackson Ward 4, Madison, Tennessee, United States; citing sheet 2B, NARA microfilm publication T625 (Washington D.C.: National Archives and Records Administration, n.d.); FHL microfilm 1,821,754.

Comment: Hi Jerome, welcome. Would you mind adding a few more details to your question so that we don't just tell you things you already know. You can add information using the [edit] button below your question. It would be useful to know basics such as which country Abram ended up in - that might lead to immigration records, etc. What makes you say he may have been from Bessarabia? Before you can start looking at where he was from you need to really flesh out his life post-immigration, otherwise you could end up searching for the wrong Abram Frank.

Comment: Hi, welcome to G&FH.SE!  We encourage all new users to take the [tour], but I would also encourage you to read the material in the [help], starting with [What topics can I ask about here?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) General "I need any information" questions can be broad, and don't always yield good answers. You can edit your question at any time by using the edit link underneath.  Asking multiple focused questions about the same person or family is okay.

Comment: Thank you for adding that additional information. Please don't be offended that I deleted the sentence about your father. I did that because he was born less than 100 years ago which means we need to be mindful of our privacy policy in the [help/on-topic]. Rather than asking for online proof of decease it is easier to remove it and I do not think that fact alters the specific question.

Comment: To look for the birth family of Betty I think you should ask a separate question so that this one can stay focussed on Abe.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "several online databases"?

Comment: By this I mean: JewishGen, geni, FamilySearch.org, MyHeritage, Ancestry, and BillionGraves.